# How to change Android Oreo launcher icon daily?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

On Android Oreo, the icon of Google Calendar is always updated with the current month day (for example today is 2018-02-09).

[image: Google Calendar]

Is this feature avaiable to all developers? For example, I would like to change the launcher icon for monthly paying users and freemium users.

Comment: I think that I saw a report on XDA that this feature might be coming in a future version of Android.

Comment: @Benjamin, is not the same question. This feature was first available on Android Nougat (launched at 2016-08-22). The question you mentioned was written 2016-01-04, thus it was not possible doing it on Android Marshmallow.